# visual c sharp progress bar with background worker

Tags: c#

i have the following code that updates my progress bar in visual c sharp. it works fine and the bar moves for each percentage. but i also have code that i got from a post on another site, that is suppose to put the progress bar value in the middle of the progress bar as % percentage. it displays the % of the progress bar value for a split second but then disappears. i am new to c sharp and have tried several things like pBar.update and pBar.refresh after the pBar value change. i have edited some of the code to make it easier to understand. see below, once i reportprogress the background worker progresschanged executes and again the pBar value changes i see it change, and also the textbox text gets updated, but for some reason the code further below that draws the % text within the progress bar gets overwritten somehow. again i see the % for a split second. you can see some of my comments where i was trying various things to see if it would redraw the %

```
         private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(10);
        collect_long_process();
        }

         private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

        txtBox_pBar.Text = "Gathering info";

        int percent = 10;//(int)(((double)pBar.Value / (double)pBar.Maximum) * 100);
        pBar.CreateGraphics().DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular),
        Brushes.Black, new PointF(pBar.Width / 2 - 10, pBar.Height / 2 - 7));
    //pBar.Update();
    //Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is wrong.

You need to handle the progress bar's `Paint` event and draw on `e.Graphics`.
Otherwise, your drawing will be overwritten next time the control paints itself.

In general, you should never draw on `CreateGraphics()`.

Comment: +1. A solution that would be more in line with standard interface conventions would be to have a label with the percentage rather than superimposing it on top of the progress bar.

Comment: @Adam: True, although inline-labeled progress bars are somewhat common.

Comment: i was over complicating it :) i tried the label it works fine.. duh . thx for the insight LOL.